# Finding the density function when you are given a transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem:
Let $Y$ be a random variable with probability density function given by
$$ f(y)  = \begin{cases}
                        2(1-y), & 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
                        0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases} $$
Find the density function of $U = 2Y - 1$.
Answer:

\begin{align*} 
P ( u \leq u_0 ) &= P ( 2(1-y) \leq u_0 ) \\
P ( u \leq u_0 ) &= P \left( (1-y) \leq \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) \\
P ( u \leq u_0 ) &=  P \left( y \geq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) \\
\end{align*}
$$  P \left( y \geq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) =
1 -  P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) $$
\begin{align*} 
 P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    \int_0^{1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2}} 2(1-y) \,\, dy \\
 P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    -(1-y)^2\Big|_0^{ 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2}} \\
P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    \left( 1 - 1 + \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right)^2 \\
P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    \dfrac{ u_0 ^2 }{4}
\end{align*}
This gives us:
$$ f(U) = 1 - \dfrac{u^2}{4}$$
$$ f(u) = \dfrac{u}{2} $$
However, the book's answer is:
$$\dfrac{1-u}{2}, \,\, -1 \leq u \leq 1 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated solution which is still wrong.

\begin{align*} 
P ( u \leq u_0 ) &= P ( 2(1-y) \leq u_0 ) \\
P ( u \leq u_0 ) &= P \left( (1-y) \leq \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) \\
P ( u \leq u_0 ) &=  P \left( y \geq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) \\
\end{align*}
$$  P \left( y \geq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) =
1 -  P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) $$
\begin{align*} 
 P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    \int_0^{1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2}} 2(1-y) \,\, dy \\
 P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    2y - y^2\Big|_0^{ 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2}} \\
 P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    2\left( 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right)
        - 2 \left( 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right)^2 \\
%
 P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    2 \left( 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2}  \right)
    - 2\left( 1 - u_0 + \dfrac{u_0^2}{4} \right) \\
%
P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    2 - u_0 - 2 + 2u_0 - \dfrac{ u_0^2}{2} \\
%
P \left( y \leq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    u_0 - \dfrac{ u_0^2}{2} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
P \left( y \geq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    1 - \left( u_0 - \dfrac{u_0^2}{2} \right) \\
P \left( y \geq 1 - \dfrac{u_0}{2} \right) &=
    u_0 + \dfrac{u_0^2}{2}
\end{align*}
This gives us:
$$ F(u) = \dfrac{u^2}{2} - u $$
$$ f(u) = u - 1 $$
However, the book's answer is:
$$\dfrac{1-u}{2}, \,\, -1 \leq u \leq 1 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Integral is wrong.  Should be $2y-y^2|_0^{1-u_0/2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ F_{_U} (u)=P(U \leq u)=P(2Y-1 \leq u)=P(Y \leq \frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{2})=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{2}} 2(1-y) \, dy = ... $$

where $-1 \leq u \leq 1$.